# Javascript Changing one object also changes the other object

Tags: javascript

In my code snippet I have an object "cat" that I store into two variables "Pelle" and "Kalle".
If I change the name of Pelle, it also changes the name of Kalle. I believe it has to do with them being references to cat.

How can I avoid this?

How can I change the value of Pelle without changing the name of Kalle?

Is the problem how I store the values in myFunction, or is the problem when I change the name in modify-function?

```
var cat = {
    name : "Melvin",
    age: : "9",
    eyeColor : "yellow"
};

var pelle;
var kalle;

myFunction(cat);
modify();
print();

function myFunction(c) {
    pelle = c;   
    kalle = c;
 }

 function modify() {
    pelle.name = "Watts";
 }

 function print() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pelle.name + " " + kalle.name;
 }
```

Output from print() is Watts Watts.

Desired output is Watts Melvin.

Comment: `pelle = c; kalle = c;` You are just creating two references to the same object

Comment: Even if it didn't pass by reference, this example would behave the same way

Comment: `pelle`, `kelle`, and `cat` are all the same object, so if you modify it, it will be modified.

Comment: That doesn't give me the solution: How do I get the output to be "Watts Melvin" instead of "Watts Watts"?

Comment: Ok, so how can I pass it by value, so I get the desired output?

Comment: You can turn `cat` into a function and then do `kelle/pelle = new Cat()` instead

Comment: Instead of making Kelle = c, you will need to make Kelle equal to a copy of c.  If you are using jquery, there is a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5164215/4843530

Comment: If you want to have two unconnected copies of an object that you can modify separately, you need to clone it. I have added a link above to a canonical question about cloning objects. A potentially better approach would be to start off with two separate objects in the first place instead of trying to repurpose one object for multiple uses.

Comment: I believe there are many ways to do it, one of them you can see here:
http://jsbin.com/qebomuh/edit?js,console

Comment: @JLRishe How do I start with two different objects in the first Place?

Comment: @chichi `var pelle = {
    name : "Melvin",
    age: : "9",
    eyeColor : "yellow"
}; var kalle = {
    name : "Melvin",
    age: : "9",
    eyeColor : "yellow"
};`